# mysqli class not found error in PHP file in Docker Container

Tags: php, mysql, database, docker, pdo

So i am running a web application in a docker container. I'm creating the images and the containers using the command 'docker-compose up'. Whenever i try to access the webpage and press the 'CTRL+U' I get the following error:

'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/mysql.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/mysql.php on line 7'

and when i use PDO I get the following error:
'Connection failed: could not find driver'.

I have the following map structur

```
dockerized-lamp (Directory)
->docker-compose.yml (File)
->DocumentRoot (Directory)
  ->PHP files
->php-apache (Directory)
  ->DockerFile
```

My  Yml File contains:

```
version: '3'
services:
    php-apache:
        image: php:7.2.1-apache
        container_name: phpapache
        ports:
        - 80:80
    volumes:
        - ./DocumentRoot:/var/www/html:z
    links:
        - 'mariadb'

mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.1
    container_name: mariadb
    volumes:
        - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        TZ: "Europe/Brussel"
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
        MYSQL_USER: 'user'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
        - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        - PMA_HOST=mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    volumes:
        - /sessions
    links:
        - mariadb

volumes:
    mariadb:
```

And my DockerFile Contains:

```
FROM php:7.2.1-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql mysql
```

And my PHP file to try to connect to the database:

```
<?php
$servername = "server";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

And my PDO PHP File is:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, 
$password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

I am trying to run these on ubuntu server 18.0.x and Debian Stretch.

Comment: Why are you using 2 different mysql apis? Plus, with the mysqli method, you never chose a database.

Comment: I choose bot APIs because these are just for testing and showing that none of them work. And i didnt choose a database because these files are made to test the connection to MYSQL and not to a database yet, i could by just adding a database at then end @FunkFortyNiner . I hope i answered your question :D